# How do i properly position my SVG element, so its even on resizes

Tags: html, css, angular, svg

So heres the image of my problem. I have two SVG files, and i want them to sticky to the bottom no matter how i resize my window, and if I resize it to a mobile configuration i want them to stack on top of eachoother

[Image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3T2B.png)

This is my CSS, but after i resize they dont stay even on the bottom. I have the background split with two different colors

```
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.column1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #679289;
}
.column2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f4c095;
}

.svg1 {
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translate(0px, 68px);
}

.svg1 {
  
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translate(0px, 166px);
}
```

Also noting the SVGs are not the same size

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try containing the elements in divs and using flex-box. You might have to adjust it for other layout elements, but the principle should be the same.

https://codepen.io/jonshipman/pen/zYRoKjX

```
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  background: transparent;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

img {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div {
  background: blue;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}

@media screen and (max-width:786px) {
  .flex {
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
  }
  
  .flex > div {
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-end;
  }
}
```